# Are there any ways to run Azure DevOps pipeline yaml file in my local machine?

Tags: docker, yaml, pipeline, docker-multi-stage-build

As far as I know, actually, I have no idea on '*how to run (**not validate**) locally my Azure DevOps yaml file*'.

I am looking for a *YAML pipeline AzureDevops to Dockerfile multi-staged* **converter** in order to generate automatically the `Dockerfile` ready to test the pipeline locally.

Let's keep this Azure DevOps multi-stage yaml file that you can find on microsoft GitHub [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/templates/python-to-linux-webapp-on-azure.yml)

```
# Python to Linux Web App on Azure
# Build your Python project and deploy it to Azure as a Linux Web App.
# Change python version to one thats appropriate for your application.
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- {{ branch }}

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureServiceConnectionId: '{{ azureServiceConnection.Id }}'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: '{{ webAppName }}'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: '{{ webAppName }}'

  # Project root folder. Point to the folder containing manage.py file.
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  # Python version: 3.7
  pythonVersion: '3.7'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : {{ webAppName }}'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

I am converting manually (that's cumbersome) my yaml files into a multi-staged Dockerfiles, something like the following, (*not related to the complex yaml file mentioned above*) in order to test my yaml file locally using `multi-stage building`, that you can find in the Official Docker documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-a-previous-stage-as-a-new-stage) (*modified a bit below*)

```
FROM alpine:latest AS builder
COPY source.cpp source.cpp
COPY source-with-unittest.cpp source-with-unittest.cpp
RUN apk --no-cache add build-base

FROM builder AS build
RUN g++ -o /binary source.cpp

FROM builder AS test
RUN g++ -o /binary-with-unittest source-with-unittest.cpp
```

---

## Expected

**Convert Tool**

```
./convert --azure-pipeline-definition azure-pipeline.yaml --dockerfile-name Multistaged-Dockerfile
..
..
..
SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED
"azure-pipeline.yaml" is converted into a multistaged dockerfile named: "Multistaged-Dockerfile"!

Test your pipeline locally running the following command

    > docker build --tag <IMAGENAME:TAG> --file Multistaged-Dockerfile
```

**Test pipeline locally with Dockerfile**

`docker build --tag testpipeline:locally --file Multistaged-Dockerfile`

In general it has been ***emulated*** the AzureDevOps remote pipeline execution in my local machine.

---

## Reasons Why

- contain azure devops pricing
- reduce queue azure devops agents load in critical days

Answer (score -1):

try to use the Azure DevOps portal there's an option to built-in validation feature in th. When you create or modify a YAML pipeline, Azure DevOps will automatically validate the syntax of the file and highlight any errors or warnings.

Comment: I know, but this is not the point I described above.. I'm looking for a local pipeline execution. You know at the moment we can run pipeline in azure devops platform simply clicking the `Run` button. I would like to run the pipeline yaml file locally in my machine emulating the remote execution with multi-stage building provided by Docker

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).